# Keep getting this error when trying to render my custom HTML form

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Here is the error I got when I removed the else clause from my views.py file.

```
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 309, in check_response      
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view register.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I'm guessing that I got this error as there is no else clause, which I need to have but if I have it in my views.py file I get another error.

Here is my view file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
        last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
        dob = request.POST['dob'],
        email = request.POST['email']
        newuser= User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, email=email)
        newuser.save()
        print(request.POST)
        return redirect('/home')
```

I originally had an else clause at the bottom of this but that caused a different error.

Here is that clause:

```
else: 
    return render('/register/userinfo.html')
```

And the error I get with it in place:

```
 File "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\Django\Sub\register\views.py", line 4, in render      
    return render(request,'/register/userinfo.html')
TypeError: render() takes 1 positional argument 
but 2 were given
```

Any idea as to what may cause this bottom error?

**Edit 1:** Just added in a request clause to the return render and got another error, this time:

```
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: register/userinfo.html
```

Looks like it can't find my template I used for the form. It's path is set up so that it is in a template folder within my app of register.

**Edit 2** Got the form to show up, but when I submit I get this Page not found error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register
Using the URLconf defined in Main.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
home/
about/
addinfo/
register/ [name='register']
The current path, register/register, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: What is the whole path to `register.html`?

Comment: The whole path would be register\templates\userinfo.html.                                           In which register is the app and templates is a folder within the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check your path to `userinfo.html`. You should not start with `/`. Try this:

```
return render(request,'userinfo.html')
```

Comment: Tried it and am still getting the same template error. Maybe if I moved it to my main templates folder?

Comment: You can try also `templates/userinfo.html` and `userinfo.html`. If still does not work, share `settings.TEMPLATES` dictionary in question post.

Comment: Ok, just tried using userinfo.html and got the form to load, but when I press submit I get a page not found error. I have it set up to where it should be sending me back to the homepage. But instead is saying that "PATH register/register does not exist"

Comment: It's another issue for another question. This one is solved. Please mark it as solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The second error message suggests that your code on line 4 was this:

```
return render(request,'/register/userinfo.html')
```

You say you else clause was:

```
else: 
    return render('/register/userinfo.html')
```

Are you sure you saved and restarted your project before testing.

Else I have no idea how this error could occur.
I suggest checking out the code of the render function to see what may cause the problem.

Comment: It restarts automatically. `return render(request, '/register/userinfo.html')` this line is fine.

Comment: `TypeError: render() takes 1 positional argument`
Well the debugger sais it only takes one argument.
Yours has two.

Comment: I don't know why it says so, but according to official docs, you have to do it with `request`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/